# LongClick with Custom TextView in ListVIew NOT WORKING

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, onclick, android-custom-view

I have a ListView which has a Custom TextView which i got from [here: FlowTextView](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView)

The problem is if i use a normal default TextView everything works perfectly fine,But if i use this custom text view all the Click Events (LongClick and OnClick) dont work if clicked inside the text view i.e. the click event only work at places where this Custom TextView doesn't reach to (The edges of my List Row).

I have tried

- android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
- android:focusable="false"
- android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

But none of it worked, or maybe i did it in the wrong way...if you think any of these methods work please elaborate on how to use this

My implementation in the FlowTextView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ff71ff34">


<uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"

    android:text="Description"


    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:background="#1b1b1f"

    android:textColor="@android:color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffbb52"/>

</uk.co.deanwild.flowtextview.FlowTextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="CodeLearn 1"
    android:background="#1b1b1f"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/></RelativeLayout>
```

inside OnCreate

```
ListView mainList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    new Connect(mainList,this).execute(aa);
    mainList.setClickable(true);
    mainList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView <?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Username/Password! TRY AGAIN!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("long clicked","pos: " + pos);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

activity_main.xml which contains the root listview

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></ListView>
```

Comment: Please Provide a reason for the downvote? I think i have done enough googling and research and posting it here is a last resort.Please mention what was left out in this question

Comment: Check line 88 of `FlowTextView.java`: [Link](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView/blob/master/flowtextview/src/main/java/uk/co/deanwild/flowtextview/FlowTextView.java#L88). That should answer your question.

Comment: @Vikram Sorry for being such an idiot but i dont understand it FlowTextVIew has already registered a listener so how do i use it or disable it?...I have no idea

Comment: I have not gone through the whole source code. From what I can tell, the `OnTouchListener` is used to support clicking of web links. This is very limiting. Try `setOnTouchListener(null)` on view with id `textView2` inside your adapter.

Comment: @Vikram yes, it's helps - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @Vikram in comments

> Check line 88 of FlowTextView.java: Link. That should answer your
>   question.

so basically the solution was to setOnTouchListener for that object to null

```
setOnTouchListener(null)
```